# What are all possible scenarios for PayPal's IPN?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Sadly, [PayPal's documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/) is woefully inadequate.

What are the possible values for `payment_status`, and when do they occur?

I am aware of:

- `Completed` - pretty self-explanatory
- `Pending` - eCheque payment that hasn't gone through yet

And... that's it. That's all that's mentioned in the documentation.

But I need to know, what other values exist? What do you get if an eCheque is denied? What about when a client <sub>(fraudulently, -mutter mutter-)</sub> issues a chargeback against a payment <sub>(and rips you off for a few hundred quid -more muttering-)</sub>, what does IPN send in these cases?

Ultimately I want to automate more of the scenarios that come up. For instance, if a Pending transaction arrives then I want to be able to reliably explain to the client that their eCheque is pending and they will be notified when it clears, and then proceed to notify them when it is indeed cleared (or denied).

Since I deal in virtual currency, I want to be able to debit a user's account automatically if they file a chargeback, but then credit them again if the chargeback is resolved and the funds returned to me.

And I really don't like how there might be other scenarios that I can't prepare for, simply because the documentation is shite.

Anyone got some hands-on experience, or are there any actual devs from PayPal who will honour this call?

[image: StackOverflow is not a "forum", guys!]

Comment: Hi, refer the following links for IPN variables: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/
You can see all the possible transaction payment status and reasons.

Comment: @Murugesh Thank you very much. So it turns out the problem with the documentation isn't it being incomplete, but rather it being difficult to find what's actually needed. Thanks again.

Comment: AFAIK, PayPal will notify through IPN for any changes on the payment status. For example, from pending state to completed IPN is triggered and notified.